# Not sure why it exits the loop (in C)

Tags: c, while-loop

I have my code to run until the user inputs "0 0 0" to stop the program
but my program stops after one loop. I tried adding a print in the inner loop to see what the values were and maybe they were all getting set 0.

my example input
5 10 6
5 3 4 2 4

output
p = 4, s = 9, c = 6
p = 3, s = 6, c = 6
p = 2, s = 4, c = 6
p = 1, s = 0, c = 6
Scenario #1: MHR rides coaster #4, using the single rider line.

I can see that p, s, and c are not all 0 so I don't know why it breaks out of the outer loop when it should just go back to asking for the 3 user input values

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int p,s,c,h,x=1,coaster;

    while(p != 0 && s != 0 && c != 0){
        //number of parties, single riders, capacity of ride
        scanf("%d%d%d",&p,&s,&c);
        //allocate memory
        int* parties = malloc(sizeof(int)*p);

        for(h=0;h<p;h++){
            //get size of each party in line
            scanf("%d",&parties[h]);
        }

        //find the faster line for each scenario
        int t = 0;
        while(p != 0 || s > 0){
            coaster = c - parties[t];
            s = s - coaster;
            p--;
            printf("p = %d, s = %d, c = %d\n",p,s,c);
            if(p == 0 && s != 0){
                printf("Scenario #%d: MHR rides coaster #%d, using the regular line.\n",x,t+1);
                break;
            }

            if(s <= 0 && p != 0){
                printf("Scenario #%d: MHR rides coaster #%d, using the single rider line.\n",x,t+1);
                break;
            }

            if(s <= 0 && p == 0){
                printf("Scenario #%d: MHR rides coaster #%d, using either line.\n",x,t+1);
                break;
            }

            t++;
        }

        x++;
        free(parties);

    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you haven't initialized p, s or c, the program will quit immediately if they happen to be zero initially. Also, your logic appears to be wrong — `(p != 0 && s != 0 && c != 0)` will be false if *any* of these variables is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop condition you are using is effectively: `p` not zero AND `c` not zero AND `s` not zero. So when `s` is zero, the condition is false and the loop exits.

The condition you are looking for is NOT (`p` is zero AND `c` is zero AND `s` is zero):

```
!(p == 0 && c == 0 && s == 0)
```

There is another bug in the program, you don't initialise `p`, `c` or `s` before checking their value.

Comment: but how can i initialize them without the user inputting the numbers first? maybe I should change it to do-while then?

Comment: Set them to some fake value (e.g. -1) just to pass the initial loop condition. The value will be overwritten by the `scanf` immediately entering the loop. You could also use a do-while construct, as you suggest.

Comment: ah thank you, and I changed the logic with the condition @Pooya offered below

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have:

```
int p,s,c,h,x=1,coaster;
while(p != 0 && s != 0 && c != 0){
```

which is not good. You check for the values of `p`, `s` and `c`, but they are **uninitialized variables**!

Comment: i would further add that OP probably wants to use a do..while loop in this scenario.

Comment: Yeah I realized that too, either just change to do while or initialize the variables something irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

if you want to quit if everything becomes zero, Change:

```
while(p != 0 && s != 0 && c != 0)
```

to:

```
while(!(p == 0 && s == 0 && c == 0))
```

Comment: thank you! Didn't realize my condition wasn't equivalent to what I actually wanted it to be.

Comment: I think I'm not doing the logic operators correctly, sorry but do you think you can tell me if the logic for the if statements near the end are correct? I'm trying other example inputs and its printing the wrong ones

Comment: @Hispazn: what are you trying to achieve?